# Haskell toEnum on data type throws range exception

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write an instance of Enum for the following type:

```
-- Type declarations:

-- Octave
data Octave =
    O1 | O2 | O3
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

-- Note
data Note = 
    A | B | C | D | E | F
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)

-- Pitch
data Pitch = Pitch Octave Note
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

-- Why doesn't this work?
instance Enum Pitch where
    fromEnum (Pitch o n) = (fromEnum o)*6 + (fromEnum n)
    toEnum x = (Pitch o n)
        where 
            o = toEnum (x `div` 6)
            n = toEnum (x `mod` 6)
```

This works fine for:

```
[(Pitch O1 A) .. (Pitch O3 F)]
```

But fails for:

```
[(Pitch O1 A) .. ]
```

With the error:

```
*** Exception: toEnum{Octave}: tag (3) is outside of enumeration's range (0,2)
```

I understand the error. 
My questions are: 
How to correctly write the Enum instance to perform this enumeration?
Is it possible?
Most of all: Is it good practice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that `Pitch` is implicitly *bounded* – i.e., it has a least and greatest element – but you don't reflect that boundedness in your code.  The code

```
[Pitch O1 A ..]
```

desugars to

```
enumFrom (Pitch O1 A)
```

which keeps `succ`ing the generated values until it `succ`s `Pitch O3 F` and blows up.  How could it know that it should stop there?

[From the Prelude documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum):

> For any type that is an instance of class [`Bounded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) as well as [`Enum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum), the following should hold:
>
> …
>
> - [`enumFrom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFrom) and [`enumFromThen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromThen) should be defined with
>     an implicit bound, thus:
>
>   ```
>   enumFrom     x   = enumFromTo     x maxBound
>   enumFromThen x y = enumFromThenTo x y bound
>     where
>       bound | fromEnum y >= fromEnum x = maxBound
>             | otherwise                = minBound
>   ```

Thus, to fix this problem, just add

```
instance Bounded Pitch where
  minBound = Pitch minBound minBound
  maxBound = Pitch maxBound maxBound
```

and then add the code from the documentation:

```
instance Enum Pitch where
  -- ...
  enumFrom     x   = enumFromTo     x maxBound
  enumFromThen x y = enumFromThenTo x y bound
    where
      bound | fromEnum y >= fromEnum x = maxBound
            | otherwise                = minBound
```

and now [Pitch O1 A ..] will stop at the end:

```
λ> [Pitch O1 A ..]
[Pitch O1 A,Pitch O1 B,Pitch O1 C,Pitch O1 D,Pitch O1 E,Pitch O1 F,Pitch O2 A,Pitch O2 B,Pitch O2 C,Pitch O2 D,Pitch O2 E,Pitch O2 F,Pitch O3 A,Pitch O3 B,Pitch O3 C,Pitch O3 D,Pitch O3 E,Pitch O3 F]
```

---

Side note: you can replace separate calls to `div` and `mod` with pattern-matching on a single call to `divMod`: `` x `divMod` y == (x `div` y, x `mod` y) ``.  (For strictly positive numbers, like these, I believe I've heard that `quotRem` may be a better choice; `quot` and `rem` are like `div` and `mod`, but with different sign-related behaviors.)  Additionally, you could replace your `6`s with `1 + (fromEnum (maxBound :: Note))` to avoid accidentally getting the number wrong.

Answer (score 6):

`[x ..]` is desugared into `enumFrom x` method, for which the [prelude provides the following default implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#enumFrom):

```
enumFrom x = map toEnum [fromEnum x ..]
```

Override it to do the right thing by your instance.  You'll also likely want to override `enumFromThen` for similar reasons.

Comment: Thanks! `enumFrom x = map toEnum [fromEnum x .. 17]` Is this good style?